What can be said about the degree of the remainder in bivariate polynomial division?
Consider the following polynomials in 2 variables: the dividend $p(x,y)$, the (linearly independent) divisors $f_1(x,y), \dots, f_s(x,y)$, the quotients $q_1(x,y),\dots,q_s(x,y)$ and the remainder $r(x,y)$, such that:
$$
p(x,y) = q_1(x,y) f_1(x,y) + \dots + q_s(x,y) f_s(x,y) + r(x,y)
$$
Denote the degree of a polynomial to be the highest sum of powers of its individual terms. For example: $g(x,y) = x^2y - x^2 $ has degree 3, and $g(x,y) = x^2y^3 + y$ has degree 5.
Let $\text{degree}(p) = n_p$, $\text{degree}(f_1) = \dots = \text{degree}(f_s) = n_f$, and assume that at least one quotient is non-zero, $\exists k: q_k(x,y) \neq 0$, for some particular choice of divisors.

What can be said about the $\text{degree}(r) = n_r$ (other than $n_p \geq n_r$)?


Nothing much can be said in general. For example, if $s=1$, $f_1(x,y)=x^2y^2$, then $r=p$ for all single variable monomials $p(x,y)=x^n$. In a multivariable setting there usually isn't even a well defined remainder $r$. The catch is that it depends on the ordering of monomials. You probably want to study Gröbner bases, Buchberger's algorithm and such. I'm not conversant enough on the theory to post an answer.

Say, if  $s=1$, $f_1=y^2-x$, it is not clear whether $r_1=yx$ or $r_2=y^3$ is the more reduced remainder. The choice $r_1$ is preferred, if you use $f_1$ to get rid of high powers of $y$, whereas $r_2$ is what you get, when you try and eliminate $x$ first.

@JyrkiLahtonen what $p$ do you assume for the second comment?

Anything in that coset of the ideal generated by $f_1$. For example $p=y^3$. See this thread in Mathematica.SE for more examples.
